# Android browser stops rendering canvas after "double swipe" scroll

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, scroll

I have a full-screen web app running on a Nexus One with Android v2.3.6. I've done everything I can to prevent scrolling. I'm calling `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the following events:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', eventCanceller, false );
document.addEventListener('touchstart',eventCanceller, false );
document.addEventListener('touchend',eventCanceller, false );
document.addEventListener('wheel',eventCanceller, false );
document.addEventListener('mousewheel',eventCanceller, false );
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',eventCanceller, false );

window.addEventListener('touchmove',eventCanceller, false );
window.addEventListener('touchstart',eventCanceller, false );
window.addEventListener('touchend',eventCanceller, false );
window.addEventListener('wheel',eventCanceller, false );
window.addEventListener('mousewheel',eventCanceller, false );
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',eventCanceller, false );

canvas.addEventListener('click',eventCanceller, false);
canvas.addEventListener('dblclick',eventCanceller, false);
```

I'm also stopping propagation and preventing default on these events, after I handle them.

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',handleEvent, false);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',handleEvent, false);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend',handleEvent, false);
```

The app works, and all unintended scrolling is suppressed. Except that, if I make two or more small swipes rapidly, the URL bar scrolls down and all rendering ceases on the canvas. There are no javascript errors, debugging shows that the app continues to run, my draw function continues to be called, and it thinks it still has a valid 2DContext, but the screen is frozen. If I use the track ball to scroll the screen, rendering starts back up. I'm seeing exactly the same on the Kindle Fire. On that device, rendering starts back up if I switch into/out of full-screen mode.

Is there any way to suppress this freezing / scrolling effect I'm seeing on "double swipe"?

Comment: After more digging, I've realized that this issue can be decoupled from the unwanted scrolling. Rendering will freeze on a trivial sample app, even without scrolling.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36475

I'm either missing something fundamental about JS event processing on Android Browser, or HTML5 gaming is in trouble on Android, given that this same issue is on both an old phone and a new (bestselling) Tablet. No game company would want to ship a product with what looks to consumers like a freeze crash.

Comment: try https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim

Answer (score 2):

I've had this.

It possibly is fixed on Android 4.1 (a lot of things to do with touch events apparently are).

On android 2.3 that I'm developing with right now, I've got a disgusting workaround, which is that I do this.

```
    // force a reflow of the canvas in case it has hung (on android)
    canvas.width = canvas.width-1;
    canvas.width=canvas.width+1;
```

I currently do it every frame (I'm only running at 20fps anyway), and it seems to work okay.

gross.